# I can't shut of the hot water completely

Tags: shower

I have a leaky shower. I bought new inserts to replace the valves in the faucet handles. I shut off the water at the main coming into the house and then removed the hot water side first. When I removed the valve a quarter inch stream of hot water continued to flow out of the pipe. As the hot water heater in in the basement and this bathroom on the floor above I don't think it a gravity issue of any kind. I replaced the valve and that stream of water continued to leak, but now out of the faucet. I can't seem to get it stopped. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some pictures? Maybe a brand or model number?

Answer (score 1):

Go back and once again turn off the water main valve where cold water enters your house. Then go to various sinks and bath areas and turn on the faucets there. These will allow the water from higher level piping to drain out and break any potential siphon action that may have been occurring in your shower where you were trying to do the repair.

There are a number of reasons why a replacement of part of that hot water valve insert may not be working:

1. The wrong style of insert is being used.
2. The insert may be too thin.
3. There is debris in the faucet body that prevents the faucet stem from being turned completely in to bottom out the insert.
4. There a crack or corrosion damage of the seat part of the valve that prevents the new insert from even working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not at home at the moment but I know the fixture is American Standard from the late 60's/early 70's. I could not find the correct American Standard replacement so used a generic analog found at a local hardware store, (so I assume #1 above may be the culprit). Just seemed weird that so much hot water came out after shutting off the main, and with such force! I waited for over an hour for the flow to diminish and it did not... Still, I will continue my search for the proper American Standard fitting.

Comment: @MarkSprowles - Is there any chance that where you tried to turn off the water supply that you were just closing a valve that fed just the cold water lines in the house? It is possible that the water heater may have been still connected to the main input...especially if you left it running for an hour.  :^)